# How to make popup window auto populate with contents in cell

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a data grid displaying results from a sql database. What I want to do is make it so that when I double click on a cell in the datagrid, a new window appears where that cell can be edited. I also would like to have all the info for that cell to be autogenerated into editable fields when the cell is double clicked. Any help or links to tutorials is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [DataGridView.CellDoubleClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using data binding? Simply put, you can bind your items list to `DataGrid`, and current item (eg. selected/double clicked) to your edit form's controls (`TextBox`, `Label` and whatever else you might have there).

Here are good starting points for windows forms: [#1](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html), [#2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databinding_tutorial.aspx). They cover problem you're facing. You can find data binding tutorials for ASP/WPF easily too, but especially first link covers entire concept pretty well.